# Restore whole OS X from damaged but yet somehow accessible HFS+ partition

Tags: linux, macos, mac, partitioning, data-recovery

Okay, here's my problem: my disk got damaged (most possibly by the power problems). Disk utility shows it in gray color and won't mount offering me to check and repair it. Needlessly to say it won't repair it (neither in Mac OS X nor in Linux).
Here's a picture showing **Disk Utility**

**Macintosh HD is listed gray in Disk Utility:**

[image]

When I try to mount it as readonly in Mac OS X i get the following error message:

```
$ sudo mount -t hfs -o rdonly /dev/disk1s2 /Volumes/OldDrive/
GetMasterBlock: Error 16 opening /dev/rdisk1s2
mount_hfs: Resource busy
```

But! Linux will mount it as readonly. Which is really good. Even more: Mac OS X booted into single user mode (cmd+S) will allow me to browse the structure and **cat** files.

I don't really want to just copy necessary files form that damaged disk from under linux. I want to restore that disk to my freshly installed one.

What will you suggest me to do?
Can I mount that disk under OS X somehow? If i can't, how can I get the data from that disk so OS X would recognize it as a backup and restore all my settings and applications into fresh installation?

Comment: Do you know whether it's an issue with the data, or whether it's a hardware problem? For the former, I've had some good experience with DiskWarrior being able to repair broken volumes.

Comment: DiskWarrior says:
Directory cannot be rebuilt due to disk hardware failure (-36, 2747)
While I was composing my post this disk got mounted somehow, but after restart it got gray again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay then. What did I do.

I booted into linux (ubuntu 13.10) and created an image of my old (unwritable) disk to the new one.
Then I formatted the old one into GUID partitions and restored IMG onto formatted old disk.

I used [partclone](http://partclone.org/) utility to backup and restore disk. It will create image of size equal to the used space of a disk. Not a bit-to-bit copy like [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) would do. And it's able to restore an image to the partition that at least the size of the image backed up.

Some would recommend you to use [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) which is actually a wrapper to a set of CLI  tools but I found its interface quite complicated.

So after all these manipulations I ended up having a disk that is not yet writable but bootable and mountable in mac os x. Which will allow Mac OS X installer to detect it as a source for restore.

If the method above won't help you getting bootable GUID disk with the partition, reformat the disk into msdos table and create regular HFS+ partition. Time Machine won't detect it as a source but you will still be able to use [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) to restore data.

Even if CCC not helping you will end up having  **osx-mountable** HFS+ partition which you can use to manually copy necessary files. Like prefs, keychains and some vital documents.

Enjoy your mac.

Thank you.